# Difference between "-fno-pie" and "-no-pie"

Tags: gcc, ld, compiler-flags, linker-flags

I don't find any useful information on the differences between "-fno-pie" and "-no-pie". Are they **gcc** flags or **ld** flags? Are they both necessary or not?

I found a piece of makefile that uses these lines:

```
CC = @gcc -fno-pie -no-pie
LD = @gcc -fno-pie -no-pie
```

So it uses **gcc** for linking instead of a direct call to **ld** but I don't understand the differences between the flags and if they are both necessary to compiling and linking stage

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** `-fno-pie` is a "code generation option" while `-no-pie` is a "linker option". You need both.

`-fno-pie` tell GCC that you *don't* want to make a PIE. If you are not making a PIE you are making either a shared object (using `-shared`) or an ordinary executable.
Ordinary executables are loaded below the 4GiB and at a fixed address, furthermore their symbols cannot be interposed so `-fno-pie` tell GCC that can translate an expression like `&foo` in something like `mov eax, OFFSET FLAT foo`.
It doesn't have to use the GOT since the symbols are not interposed and it doesn't have to use RIP-relative addressing since a 32-bit address fits in the 32-bit immediate/displacement of x86-64 instructions.

[Check out what `-fpie`/`-fno-pie` do in terms of assembly instructions.](https://godbolt.org/z/Txa414Prn)

An instruction like `mov eax, OFFSET FLAT foo` creates a `R_X86_64_32` relocation, this relocation is used in 64-bit programs when the compiler is sure that an address will always fit 32 bits (i.e. is below 4GiB).
However `-fno-pie` *doesn't* stop GCC from passing `-pie` to the linker.
So the linker sees a `R_X86_64_32` relocation and is still instructed to make a PIE executable. The relocation promises that the address will be below 4GiB but the `-pie` flag promises that the executable is meant to be loaded anywhere, including above 4GiB.
These contrast each other and the linker is required to check this stalemate and produce an error.

To tell the linker that indeed you did not want to link a PIE executable, you need to pass `-no-pie` to GCC.

You can pass `-v` to GCC while compiling a file to see what options are passed to `collect2` (a wrapper to the linker).
Regardless of the presence of `-fno-pie`, `-pie` is still passed to `collect2`.
Adding `-no-pie` to GCC will suppress `-pie` in the `collect2` command line.

**Note**: Older distributions built GCC without defaulting to `-fpie -pie`.

Comment: It might be more clear to say that `-fpie` is a "code generation option" (like most `-f` options are), and `-pie` is a "linking option" (does not affect generated assembly, just passed through by the compiler driver to the linker).

Comment: Based on **TLDR;** what I need is `CC = @gcc -fno-pie` and `LD = @gcc -no-pie`, isn't it? So I don't need both in the 2 script lines